# Нахождение строки между символом

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
import re
comp = re.compile(r'¬(.*?)¬')
m = comp.findall('¬AG÷0¬BA÷0¬BB÷0¬')
print(m)
```

Получаю ['AG÷0', 'BB÷0']

Мне нужно ['AG÷0', 'BA÷0', 'BB÷0']

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что регулярные выражения ищут в строке последовательно, с учётом всех символов, а не только запомненных. То есть, когда ваша регулярка находит первое совпадение:

> ¬AG÷0¬

Она запоминает выражение из скобок:

> AG÷0

И отбрасывает **всю** совпавшую подстроку (она же её уже проверила), оставляя для дальнейшего поиска следующую подстроку:

> BA÷0¬BB÷0¬

В которой находит единственное точное совпадение:

> ¬BB÷0¬

И сохраняет:

> BB÷0

Работающее регулярное выражение, для вашего случая, выглядит так:

```
comp = re.compile(r'¬([^¬]*)')
```

Но @insolor прав в том, что для вашей задачи регулярка - слишком сложное решение.

Answer (score 1):

> Что делаю не так?

Вы используете регулярные выражения для этой задачи )

Можно сделать намного проще:

```
s = '¬AG÷0¬BA÷0¬BB÷0¬'
print(s.split('¬'))
```

Вывод:

```
['', 'AG÷0', 'BA÷0', 'BB÷0', '']
```

Можно удалить первый и последний элементы:

```
print(s.split('¬')[1:-1])  # Вывод: ['AG÷0', 'BA÷0', 'BB÷0']
```